# animate UIImage in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiimageview

I am trying to have my uiimageview move in a straight line horizontally out of bounds and loop again starting from the other side... this is the code I have in swift..
and was wondering if anyone knows how  I can implement it in objective c?

```
let carSpeed = 20.0 / Double(view.frame.size.width)
let duration: NSTimeInterval = Double(view.frame.size.width - car.frame.origin.x) * carSpeed
UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: 0.0, options: .CurveLinear, animations:
                           {
                               car.frame.origin.x = self.view.bounds.size.width
                           }, completion: {_ in
                               //reset cloud
                               car.frame.origin.x = -self.carImageView.frame.size.width
                               self.animateCars(car)
```

also if anyone knows any tutorials on objective C animations! thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your exact code converted to Objective-C:

```
double carSpeed = 20.0 / self.view.frame.size.width;
NSTimeInterval duration = (self.view.frame.size.width - car.frame.origin.x) * carSpeed;

[UIView animateWithDuration:duration
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                 animations:^{
                     car.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width,
                                            car.frame.origin.y,
                                            car.frame.size.width,
                                            car.frame.size.height);
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     if (finished) {
                         car.frame = CGRectMake(-self.carImageView.frame.size.width,
                                                car.frame.origin.y,
                                                car.frame.size.width,
                                                car.frame.size.height);
                         [self animateCars:car];
                     }
                 }];
```

Answer (score 1):

your can set the frame of image view first

```
 UIImageView * imageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame(x,y,width,height)];
```

Then set the frames in the following method

```
int moveValue=10 // add your desired value

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
imageView.frame=CGRectMake(x+moveValue,y,width,height);
} completion:nil];
```

Comment: this still did not work/...int moveValue=10; // add your desired value
     [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^
    {
         cloudImage.frame = CGRectMake(cloudImage.frame.origin.x + moveValue, cloudImage.frame.origin.y, cloudImage.frame.size.width, cloudImage.frame.size.height);
    } completion:nil];

Comment: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   // add your code here
});